# How do I use a botton click event to capture text input from fields in Plotly Dash?

Tags: python, user-interface, graph, plotly, plotly-dash

I would just like to use something I type in a field in my background program when I push a button.

```
app.layout = html.Div([html.Div(
    [
        html.H1('K7'),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph", style={'width': '100vw', 'height': '70vh'}),
    ]),
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Input(
                id="input_symbol",
                value="TJX",
                type="text",
                placeholder="SYMBOL",
                style={'width': '10vw', 'height': '3vh'}
            ),
            dcc.Input(
                id="input_resolution",
                value="D",
                type="text",
                placeholder="RESOLUTION",
                style={'width': '10vw', 'height': '3vh'}
            )
        ])
])


@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    Input('input_symbol', 'value'),
    Input('input_resolution', 'value'))
```

Right now, as it set up there, it captures the field when I click away. All help is appreciated.

Thank You

I found the Plotly Dash documentation confusing. I implemented the example I showed but I really don't know how to do it with a button.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        [
            html.H1('K7'),
            dcc.Graph(id="graph", style={'width': '100vw', 'height': '70vh'}),
        ]
    ),
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Input(
                id="input_symbol",
                value="TJX",
                type="text",
                placeholder="SYMBOL",
                style={'width': '10vw', 'height': '3vh'}
            ),
            dcc.Input(
                id="input_resolution",
                value="D",
                type="text",
                placeholder="RESOLUTION",
                style={'width': '10vw', 'height': '3vh'}
            ),
            html.Button('Push Me!', id='button'),
        ]
    )
])
```

In this example, I added a button to your layout and created a callback function that is triggered when the button is clicked. The function takes the values of the "input_symbol" and "input_resolution" fields as input and does something with them (in this case, it generates a plot and returns it as a dictionary to update the 'figure' property of the 'graph' component). The button click event is used as a trigger for the callback function.

You can modify the "update_figure" function to perform any action you want with the values entered in the fields. Just remember to update the appropriate component properties with the results of your action.